# Find the radius of convergence and the interval of convergence for the following power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2x-1)^n}{5^n \sqrt{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the radius of convergence and the interval of convergence for the following power series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2x-1)^n}{5^n \sqrt{n}}$$

I use the ratio test:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(2x-1)^{n+1}}{5^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}}\frac{5^n\sqrt{n}}{(2x-1)^n}\right| = \left|\frac{2x-1}{5}\right| < 1$$

Therefore $0 < x < 5$

Is that the interval of convergence or do I gotta show what happen when its x = 0 and x = 5.

x = 0 case:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{5^n \sqrt{n}}$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{5^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}} \frac{5^n\sqrt{n}}{(-1)^n}\right| = \frac{1}{5} < 1$$

Therefore it doesn't Absolutely converge.

Letting $f(n) = a_n $ $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0 $

And since $\frac{1}{5^n \sqrt{n}} > \frac{1}{5^{n+1} \sqrt{n+1}}$ Does Conditionally converge

x = 5 case:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(9)^n}{5^n \sqrt{n}}$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(9)^{n+1}}{5^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}} \frac{5^n\sqrt{n}}{(9)^n}\right| = \frac{9}{5} < 1$$

Therefore it absolutely converges by the ratio test

Is this how I would properly answer this question?

Comment: You should have  $\bigg|\frac{2x-1}{5}\bigg|<1$?

Comment: Yes sorry. I changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given power series is 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2x-1)^n}{5^n \sqrt{n}}.$$

Lets take a look to what you've done. We have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(2x-1)^{n+1}}{5^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}}\cdot\frac{5^n\sqrt{n}}{(2x-1)^n}\right| = \bigg|\frac{2x-1}{5}\bigg|.$$ The series converges if 
$$\bigg|\frac{2x-1}{5}\bigg|<1$$
that is, we get $-2<x<3$. Do the test at the endpoints.

@$x=-2$, the series becomes $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}.$$ This series converges by using the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). In fact, this series converges conditionally.

@$x=3$, the series becomes $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$ This series diverges being a [$p$-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#P-series) with $p=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Oh okay I get it. Question though. What happens if it diverges in any of the points? Does it matter if it conditionally / absolutely converges? After saying the cases at which they div / conv is the question done?

Comment: @Tinler You don't need to talk about AC or CC once the series is divergent at a particular point. In the question, the series converges absolutely (as what the  Ratio Test said) for all $x$ such that $-2<x<5$. At the endpoint $x=-2$, the series converges conditionally.